# PushViewController didn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a simple app, with only 2 empty page, the first one have a button, for call an action, with the code:

```
let story = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testId")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

My second page got for Id "testId", it's two new page, I don't change param, or nothing else.

Comment: Are your view controller is part of a navigation controller?  You can actually create a transition like this purely from the storyboard, no code needed.

Comment: Change this `let story = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
` with `let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`

Comment: Also check your `self.navigationController` is not nil

Comment: Make sure your button is connected properly to an IBAction and that your ViewController is under a [NavigationController](http://imgur.com/a/Lha8w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure your first view controller has a navigation controller embedded with it,as pushing the view controller require a navigation controller'.It will surely work then.